# Ways to clean up my yes/no prompts in powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell

So, for work they gave me this "automation" script they wanted to employ. But I've literally never written anything in Powershell so naturally I re-wrote the whole thing from scratch cause it was booty (not that mine is much better) but after 5 days of Powershell experience I think I've made decent progress. However, my yes/no prompts get quite messy and I hope the people who actually know what they're doing here have some tips for me. So here's my code.

These are the prompt declarations...

```
    $yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&yes"
    $no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&no"
    $help = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&help"
    $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no, $help)


These are part of the checks for the Datacenter portion. (The whole script block is Datacenters, Clusters, Hosts utilizing VMware PowerCLI.)

    While ($ChoiceTask -eq "Check Datacenters"){
        Clear-Host
        Write-Output "Would you like to create any Datacenters?"
            $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
                switch($result){
                    0{$ChoiceTask = "Datacenters"
                    $MadeDatacenters = $true}
                    1{$ChoiceTask = "Check Clusters"
                    $MadeDatacenters = $false}
                    2{
                Write-Output "A virtual datacenter is a container for all the inventory objects required to
    complete a fully functional environment for operating virtual machines.
    Recommended procedure is creating three datacenters. The UCS Datacenter, the vSAN
    Datacenter, and the Witness Datacenter. However, you may change this to fit your needs."
                Read-Host -Prompt "(Press 'Enter' to continue)"
                    }
                }
    }

    #Creates appropriate amount of Datacenters for User

    While ($ChoiceTask -eq "Datacenters"){
        Clear-Host
        $DataCenterAmount = ([String] $DataCenterAmount = (Read-Host "How many datacenters would you like to create?"))
        Clear-Host
        Write-Color -Text "You want to create ","$DataCenterAmount ","Datacenters. Is this correct?" -Color White,Yellow,White
        $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)
            switch ($result){
                0{
                    Clear-Host
                    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$DatacenterArray = @()
                    $Curr = 1
                    While ($Curr -le $DataCenterAmount){ #Processes amount of datacenters to be created.
                        Write-Color -Text "Please enter the name of Datacenter ","$Curr",":" -Color White,Yellow,White
                        $DatacenterName = Read-Host
                        Clear-Host
                        Write-Color -Text "The name of Datacenter"," $Curr"," is"," $DatacenterName",". Is this correct?" -Color White,Yellow,White,Yellow,White
                        $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)
                            switch ($result){
                                0{ #After confirmation of Datacenter name - creates datacenter
                                $folder = Get-Folder -NoRecursion
                                try {
                                New-Datacenter -Name $DatacenterName -Location $folder
                                }
                                catch{
                                    Clear-Host
                                    Write-Color -text "[WARNING] An error has occured during the Datacenter creation process, a connection error may have ocurred." -color red
                                    Read-Host "(Press 'Enter' to continue:)"
                                    $ChoiceTask = "Standard Check"
                                }
                                $DatacenterArray.Add($DatacenterName)
                                Clear-Host
                                Write-Color -Text "Datacenter"," $DatacenterName"," successfully created! (Press 'Enter' to continue)" -Color White,Yellow,White
                                Read-Host
                                $Curr++
                                Clear-Host
                                }
                                1{}
                            }
                    }
                $ChoiceTask = "Check Clusters"
                }#End 'Yes' Selection
                1{}
            }
    }
```

As you can see, it gets really messy. But it's important the user makes sure that their choices are correct. From what I can tell this is the best way to yes/no prompt; but I'd like to really clean this up for my sake. If you missed the above, this is in conjunction with VMware's PowerCLI so if you don't recognize some actions that's why. And write-color is a custom function in order to simplify coloring of variables printed on screen. Even though I'm sure there's a much easier way to do that as well.

Comment: Is the desire for custom colors preventing the use of `$message` in the `PromptForChoice()` calls?

Comment: Use [Here-strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) to define multi-line messages you want indented. I'd think about a hash table/dictionary for all your arious prompts & messages.

Comment: Use the [`-f`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f) operator to combine literal strings with string variables: `'"{0}" is the currnet path' -f (gl).Path`

Comment: This casting is unnecessary: `[System.Collections.ArrayList]$DatacenterArray = @()`. `$DatacenterArray = @()` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I'm very much learning this all as I go so I appreciate the effort. I'll play around with a few of these suggestions and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) to pass long/large parameter sets to increase readablity:

```
$splat = @{
  'Text' = ('The name of Datacenter ', $Curr, ' is ', $DatacenterName, '. Is this correct?')
  'Color' = (White,Yellow,White,Yellow,White)
}
Write-Color -Text $Text -Color $Color
```

Consider a wrapper Function:

```
Function Ask-ColoredQuestion ($Text, $Color) {
   Write-Color -Text $Text -Color $Color
   $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
}

$splat = @{
  'Text' = ('The name of Datacenter ', $Curr, ' is ', $DatacenterName, '. Is this correct?')
  'Color' = (White,Yellow,White,Yellow,White)
}

$Result = Ask-ColoredQuestion @splat
```

Even better, [text color can be controlled via escape codes that can be part of your string](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/how-to-use-ansi-vt100-formatting-in-powershell-ooh-pretty-colors/). This will allow you to use the in-built `-Prompt` parameter of `Read-Host` or `$message` in `PromptForChoice()`

```
$esc = "$([char]27)"
$Red = "$esc[31m"
$Green = "$esc[32m"
$message = '{0}{1} {2}{3}' -f $Red, 'Hello', $Green, 'World'
$message
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXuUm.png)

So you might want to re-tool `Write-Color` to compose a string with color escape codes and then pass that string to the buit-in prompts.

I think that's enough to get you started! :D

Comment: I will definitely look into your color solution once sober, however my strings contain different amount of variables depending on what I'm asking the user. However, I'm more looking for ways to clean up the actual "if yes then" statements. Because after multiple confirmations there is A LOT of curly braces to keep track of. I have no idea what best practice with Powershell is when it comes to prompting the user multiple times. Is this the best way I can do it? Or would you (I'm assuming an experienced Powershell scripter) do it differently?

Comment: Not sure. Having trouble finding those prompts in all this code, hence my suggestions to improve readability.

Comment: Varying quantities of literals & variables can be passed to a function using arrays/lists as in my example. When you hit a certain number of options, a form-driven input is preferable, but forms are a pain in **PowerShell**. Barring that, you might loop through all data collection and then present summary confirmation and then create your DataCenters.

Comment: Yes, I intend to essentially convert this script into something form based once I know what I'm doing a little bit more. But for now this script will suffice and it's somewhat in my knowledge comfort zone.

Comment: I forgot to get back to you but since this scripts asks for a lot of already existing data, I ended up with using out-gridview to make it more user friendly. So far it's working great!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was doing a lot of prompts for yes/no answers, so I wrote a function to make it easier.  This may provide you a few tips, but you may want to improve on my effort.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Prompts user for answer to a yes no prompt.
.DESCRIPTION
    The user is prompted with the argument, and asked for a reply.
    If the reply matches YES or NO (case insensitive) the value is true
    or false.  Otherwise, the user is prompted again.
#>
function ask-user {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [string] $question
    )
    Process {
       $answer = read-Host $question
       if ("YES","YE","Y" -contains $answer) {$true}
       elseif ("NO", "N" -contains $answer) {$false}
       else {ask-user $question}
    }
} # End function ask-user
```

Comment: I actually did try something like this. Though I had trouble with implementation due to certain yes/no prompts setting variables referenced further down the line. So, using something like your ask-user function would overwrite the $answer variable upon a new prompt. And I don't exactly know how to implement something like $_ to work with this.

Comment: $answer has a lexical scope that is bounded by the function.  Outside that scope, $answer could be used for a different purpose.